# How to force an order in migrations in c# EF core 2.0 code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two tables: "Parents" and "Children":

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ParentExternalId { get; set; }
}
```

This will generate the following SQL script:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20171222072010_Initial')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [Parents] (
        [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
        [ExternalId] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
        [Description] nvarchar(300) NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Parents] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
    );
END;

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20171222072010_Initial')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [Children] (
        [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
        [ExternalId] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
        [Description] nvarchar(300) NULL,
        [ParentExternalId] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Children] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
    );
END;
```

Now I change the foreign key in Child:

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    #region foreign keys
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    #endregion foreign keys
}
```

This generates this SQL script:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20180604085531_ChangeForeignKey')
BEGIN
    DECLARE @var49 sysname;
    SELECT @var49 = [d].[name]
    FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
    INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
    WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'Children') AND [c].[name] = N'ParentExternalId');
    IF @var49 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [Transactions] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var49 + '];');
    ALTER TABLE [Children] DROP COLUMN [ParentExternalId];
END;

GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20180604085531_ChangeForeignKey')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [Children] ADD [ParentId] int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
END;

GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20180604085531_ChangeForeignKey')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [Children] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Children_Parents_ParentId] FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [Parents] ([Id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION;
END;
GO
```

Because of the order in the migration, I loose data. I want the script to first add the new column "ParentId", then update the new column and after that, drop column "ParentExternalId".

Is there a way I can force this?

Comment: You could edit the generated script, but first consider why the script isn't setting up a new constraint..

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't post everything, the foreign key constraint was scripted:

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20180604085531_ChangeForeignKey')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [Children] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Children_Parents_ParentId] FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [Parents] ([Id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION;
END;

GO


This fails of course if you don't update Children.ParentId first with the proper values

Comment: I edited my question to make clear the foreign key constraint is also created

Comment: The generated scripts are just meant to be starting points for the migration, they are not set in stone. It is not only completely supported, but *expected* that the developer will tweak them in many cases.

Comment: But then "code first" isn't really an advantage, isn't it

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Just edit the migration.cs file. It contains something like migrationBuilder.AddColumn... Move this before the migrationBuilder.DropColumn...

In between you can manually add:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(
@"
    UPDATE c SET c.ParentId = p.Id
    FROM Children AS c
    INNER JOIN Parents AS p ON ...
    WHERE c.ParentId <> p.Id
");
```